# File Share Content Connector in Azure for Search

Tags: windows, azure, powerbi, office365

I have a large number of documents, word/excel/pdf etc stored across a number of windows file shares, not sure on the total size but will be min a few TBs of files. I need an interface to search these documents (including their contents) and preview/download documents that match the search. It's also important that ACLs are respected, only returning search results for files the logged in user has access to.

The initial idea was to use a tool like Apache Tika to get the file contents/meta data and dump it all into elastic or something similar. The biggest challenge with this idea is respecting the ACLs and filtering search results.

Is there an obvious Office365/Azure solution to this? I'm a newbie with Azure and it's a bit of a minefield but have seen I can use an on premise gateway to connect file share's to power apps and other azure tools. So hoping there's functionality available that will allow me to create a front end to search through these file shares etc.

Answer (score 0):

Two separated questions in here. You can use Azure Search which has indexers capable to extract and index the content of your files with 0 lines of code. However, due the large amount of data, the billing will not be cheap and you'll need several partitions which also increase the cost.

About authentication / authorization, you'll need a [frontend](http://azsearchstore.azurewebsites.net/azsearchgenerator/index.html) to display the results, so you'd better implement the authentication / authorization on it, and let Azure Search only for the query part. You can grant permission just to your front end.

PS: You can use Azure AD for authentication part, but there's no ready to use functionality to assign which information each user can see. You'll need to implement this part